# carrierwave backgrounder s3 recreate_versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm trying to follow https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog instructions, but I was getting errors. my file is called `hat.jpg`

I'm using carrierwave_backgrounder so i needed these instructions to process immediately.

```
with_avatar.each do |instance|
    begin
      instance.process_avatar_upload = true
      instance.avatar.cache_stored_file!
      instance.avatar.retrieve_from_cache!(instance.avatar.cache_name)
      instance.avatar.recreate_versions!
      instance.save!
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.info("ERROR: UserAvatar: #{instance.id} -> #{e}")
    end
  end
```

So, i tried it in my console one line at a time. If I set process_avatar_upload = true, the next line fails

```
undefined method `cached?' for nil:NilClass
```

If i run the same command again i get

```
undefined method `content_length' for nil:NilClass
```

Finally, if I run a third time, it seems to work. However, when i get to the recreate_versions! I get this:

```
No such file or directory [my file path]/uploads/tmp/1454615129-9112-7053/square_hat.jpg
```

Its correct, there is no square, because that's what I'm trying to create.

How can I recreate my versions on s3? I have a lot of them to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'should' be enough:

```
instance.process_avatar_upload = true
instance.avatar.recreate_versions!
```

Refer to:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L216

If you are using the official gem, which is quite old (0.10.0) you should give master a chance. If you have no special version setup like `:from_version => :foo` or nested versions like

```
version :foo do
  version :foobar do
    [...]
  end
end
```

it should work as before. (But try that in non-production (!) )

Comment: Ok, so I did change to using just the two lines mentioned above. I also am now using master. And I removed the from_versions I was using. All of this allowed me to recreate_versions. Thank you!